# Why is there no sound in the local push notifications when the screen is locked?

Tags: ios, audio, push-notification

I create local push notifications on a real iPhone, for example at 10:00. I lock the screen and expect the push to appear along with the sound, but the push appears without sound.

On the simulator, if you press CMD +L (it is assumed that the screen is locked), the sound is played along with the appearance of a push, but not on a real device.

Here is my code:

```swift
func scheduleDailyAlarm(date: Date,
                               soundName: String,
                               completion: @escaping (ErrorType) -> Void) {
           
           center.getNotificationSettings { settings in
               guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else {
                   print("Notification authorization not granted")
                   completion(.error("Notification authorization not granted"))
                   
                   return
               }
               
               let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
               
               content.title = "Title"
               content.body = "Body"
               content.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: UNNotificationSoundName(rawValue: soundName))

               var dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour,.minute], from: date)

               let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents,
                                                           repeats: true)
               let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: self.alarmID,
                                                   content: content,
                                                   trigger: trigger)
               
               self.center.add(request) { (error) in
                   if let error = error {
                       print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                       completion(.error(error.localizedDescription))
                   } else {
                       print("Alarm scheduled to \(dateComponents.hour ?? 0):\(dateComponents.minute ?? 0)")
                       completion(.success)
                   }
               }
           }
       }
```

How can I make the sound play on a real device along with the push?

I'm using Xcode version 14.3.1 (14E300c)
Deployment target iOS 14
Simulator iOS 16.4
Real iPhone 16.6.1
The sound file is located in the project and less than 30 seconds

I don't know how to solve problem

Comment: 1. Does the sound play on a real device if the screen isn't locked? 2. Is the real device setup to allow sounds from notifications? 3. Does the sound name you provide exactly match (including case) the sound filename? Case matters on a real device but not on a simulator.

Comment: 1) Yes, on a real device, the sound is played if the screen is not locked, even if the application is in the determined state
2) Yes, it is
3) Yes, it is

Comment: Some body can help me?